# How to display progress in the title bar of windows explorer window?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, progress-bar

I'm trying to display a progress in Windows Explorer window using C# and imported methods from win api. 
I want the window to display a 'busy' cursor and also display a progress at the top of the window (the title bar). here's an example:

[image: Windows progress]

I tried the following solution: 
I have the window handle and I'm trying to send the right WM_MESSAGE to the window so it will display the progress. 
Using Spy++ I found out that when the window displays the progress bar it gets the following messages:

```
'WM_USER+401, 
WM_USER+402,
WM_USER+403'
```

These messages seems to update the progress bar but when I use them nothing happens.

Does anyone know how to display this progress bar in Windows?

Comment: Are you remote controlling that window or have you written some kind of shell extension? Right now I'd think that its possible that Explorer will filter messages based on their origin? Also is your program (assuming it's no extension) running with admin rights? Maybe UAC is blocking you? Have you tried sending other window messages to ensure the messages arrive?

Comment: That progress control is not available for customized use.

Comment: Mario:
My code is running as a namespace extension (in C#).
I tried changing the title and succeeded.

Raymmond:
Do you have any reference for this?